# invoice (receipt) program in python. How to prevent overwriting old values

Tags: python, css, python-3.x, while-loop

I'm a new learner for python and I'm trying to make a program that prints in invoice of all the items + their price + their quantity. each item is in separate line.

I have got tot he point where I print each item in a line, but I keep overwriting the old values by the last value entered. how can I prevent this?
this is the code:

```
    print("This program prints your invoices."
      "\nPlease enter the item identification, item cost and quantity sold when promted."
      "\nEnter 'done' when no more items"
      "\n=========================================")
saveqty= ()
savetprice=()
qtysum= 0 #quantity =qty for short
sumprice=0
list1 = []
totalprice=0
while True:
    itemid = input('Item identification: ')
    if itemid == "done":
        break


    if len(itemid)<3:
        print("item identification should be at least 3 characters long, try again")
        continue
    else:
        list11 = list[itemid]
        list1 +=[itemid]

    qtysold = input("Qty sold: ")
    try:
        qtysold =int(qtysold)
    except ValueError:
        print("must be an integer value, try again")
        continue
    qtysum+=qtysold


    try:
        itemprice = float(input("Item price: "))
        savetprice= (itemprice)
    except ValueError:
        print("item price must be numerical value, try again")
        continue

    totalprices= (qtysold*itemprice)
    totalprice+=totalprices



for elem in list1:
    print(qtysold,'x ',elem, '@ ', savetprice, 'SAR', '===', totalprices)

total = sumprice
itemtotal = qtysum
print("=========================================\nNo. of items purchased: ", itemtotal,"\nTotal price is: ", totalprice, "SAR")
```

---

Comment: Quick question, what's going on in the line `list11 = list[itemid]`?

Comment: hi @jidicula, no idea lol. during my class about lists, one of the examples, used a similar code. I used it to implement my code. but it is not needed right? I wanted to convert itemid into a list.

Comment: My concern was more that it seems to be a typo, because `list` itself is a `type` object, and `type` objects aren't subscriptable.

Comment: If you want to convert `itemid` to a list to concatenate to `list1`, you could instead surround it with square brackets: `[itemid]`. Alternatively, you could just append to `list1` with `list1.append(itemid)`.

Comment: I just tried using what you suggested, and it works. I understand it better now. thank very much for you help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the code that fixes your problem

```
print("This program prints your invoices."
      "\nPlease enter the item identification, item cost and quantity sold when promted."
      "\nEnter 'done' when no more items"
      "\n=========================================")
saveqty = ()
savetprice = ()
qtysum = 0  # quantity =qty for short
sumprice = 0
list1 = []
totalprice = 0

while True:
    itemid = input('Item identification: ')
    if itemid == "done":
        break

    if len(itemid) < 3:
        print("item identification should be at least 3 characters long, try again")
        continue

    qtysold = input("Qty sold: ")
    try:
        qtysold = int(qtysold)
    except ValueError:
        print("must be an integer value, try again")
        continue
    qtysum += qtysold

    try:
        itemprice = float(input("Item price: "))
        savetprice = (itemprice)
    except ValueError:
        print("item price must be numerical value, try again")
        continue

    totalprices = (qtysold * itemprice)
    totalprice += totalprices

    list1.append((itemid, qtysold, savetprice, totalprices))

for elem, qtysold, savetprice, totalprices in list1:
    print(qtysold, 'x ', elem, '@ ', savetprice, 'SAR', '===', totalprices)

total = sumprice
itemtotal = qtysum

print("=========================================\nNo. of items purchased: ", itemtotal, "\nTotal price is: ", totalprice, "SAR")
```

Output:

```
This program prints your invoices.
Please enter the item identification, item cost and quantity sold when promted.
Enter 'done' when no more items
=========================================
Item identification: 123
Qty sold: 5
Item price: 20
Item identification: 456
Qty sold: 3
Item price: 30
Item identification: done
5 x  123 @  20.0 SAR === 100.0
3 x  456 @  30.0 SAR === 90.0
=========================================
No. of items purchased:  8 
Total price is:  190.0 SAR
```

Note: You need to save all the information (e.g., `itemid`, `qtysold`) in the `while` loop to `list1` if you want to print them out later. Otherwise, `qtysold` and `totalprices` will always keep the last value when exiting the `while` loop. This explains the reason for the problem you are facing.

Comment: Thank you very much. I appreciate your help very much. it makes sense now